# Knockout jquery dialog binding does not work

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I've used RP Niemeyer's jquery dialog example for my project, but it does not work. The template binding complains that it cant find the member on my model (When the root model is created I set the dialog template data member to an empty observable)

Here's a simplified fiddle that reproduces the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/NnkQB/

In my eyes my code is exactly like he's but im using prototype for the methods, shouldnt matter

edit: what fixes the problem is to add a reference to jquery template engine, missed that one in the example. But I dont want dependencies to jquery template engine. Is there a bug in knockout?

Answer (score 4):

Your fiddle is failing because it is trying to render the details-dialog div before you have selected a number, and therefore called showDetails.  As you have initialized detailsItem to an empty observable - which doesn't have a number property - you are getting a JavaScript error.

One way to fix this is to add an if condition around your div, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/NnkQB/2/

Edit: I also had to change the way the dialog is cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having a hard time with the dialog clean up and your edit saved the day.